# What does this sequence look like?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n \in \{0,9\}$ and such that, for any integer $k$, there are $k$ consecutive $n$'s with $a_n =0$ and $k$ consecutive integers with $a_n =9$. Let $x \in (0,1)$ be the real number with decimal expansion $x=a_0.a_1a_2 \ldots$. What does this $x$ look like?

Comment: So is $x=0.09009900099900009999...$ ?

Comment: @uzman I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Well then $x=0.090099000999...$ :)

Comment: @uzman it's just worded very oddly. Why can't it be something else? Like say, switch the 0's and 9's or move them in different orders as in $x=0.0099000999090000099999$ etc

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yeah, the definition of $x$ is quite loose: it says nothing but that the decimal expansion of $x$ contains all finite sequences of $0$ and all finite sequences of $9$s.

Comment: @uzman so really it could be $x=. 9999990909099900909090909...$ completely random for a good while..

Comment: But since the question talks about "the" $x$ but not the set of such $x$'s, probably $x=0.090099000999...$ is your best bet.

Comment: If you take the definition in the proper sense, yes.

Comment: @uzman I've been asked to prove something about this $x$ as well, which seems again, quite odd

Comment: Maybe you should add that to your question as well?